# Modify time part of timestamptz in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

How do I modify the time part of the timestamptz field in the below table

```
+------------------------+
|   Col1::timestamptz    |
+------------------------+
| 2009-11-10 23:00:00+00 |
+------------------------+
```

to

```
+------------------------+
|   Col1::timestamptz    |
+------------------------+
| 2009-11-10 20:00:00+00 |
+------------------------+
```

in postgresql ? Is it possible to modifiy the time time part without adding intervals ?

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to use a combination of `make_timestamptz()` and `date_part()` to compose a new timestamp out of the parts.